# python- try data upload to mysql except write txt

Tags: python, mysql

I have written a loop that uploads some data to a MySQL database. When the wifi is not working, it is supposed to write the data on a txt file instead. The problem is that it does not write the txt file. I have initialised the database (called it "database") and cursor (called it "cursor"). The txt file is called "test".

EDIT: by experimenting plugging in and out the ethernet cable, I realised that when I replug the cable, a bunch of data is automatically sent with the same timestamp (maybe saved in ram or some cache- this happens whenever I restart the programme as well but on smaller scale). Do you think there might be another way to get a back up? Maybe by writing everything on txt file and erasing the txt file after every 1GB of data (so that the SD won't get full- it's on a Raspberry Pi 2)?

```
try:
  try:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES(%s)""", (temperature))
    database.commit
  except:
    text=open("test.txt","a")
    test.write(temperature + "\n")
    test.close()
except:
  print "FAIL"
```

Comment: Sometimes it works, writing only a few of the values. But most of the times it does nothing while the connection is down. The loop continues when the connection is back up again

Answer (score 0):

Since write() function expects a character buffer object, you might need to typecast temperature to string while passing it as argument to the write function.

```
test.write(str(temperature) + "\n")
```

Comment: well I fixed that (it wasn't the problem), but like I 've mentioned, it tends to work sometimes (when i reboot the system) but after that it doesn't. Also, when it does work, it gives me the wrong values. I have a time timestamp on the values so I know that the values I get are the ones that are also uploaded to the database.'

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
import urllib, time, mysqldb


time.sleep(1) # Protects Overlap from execfile
url = "https://www.google.co.uk/"


try:
   checkcon = urllib.urlopen(url)
except Exception as e:
    """
    If the program gets a socket error
    it goes to sleep, after that it restarts
    and closes this Script
    """
    time.sleep(5)# retry timer
    execfile('/path/to/your/file.py')
    raise IOError(e)


# Now that you know connection is working
try:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES(%s)""", (temperature))
    database.commit()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError as e:
    # Database Error
    with open ('test.txt'), 'a' as f:
        f.write(temperature)
        f.close()
    raise IOError(e)
```

Comment: I will try that. In which part of the code does it write the measurements to the txt file?

Comment: It doesn't, it will retry writing that entry to your Mysql db until it has an internet connection or go back into sleep mode. So you wont have to deal with csv backup system.

Comment: But it is critical that I have every "lost" measurement. How can I edit this by adding a part that writes to a txt file?

Comment: Added line at mysql exception

Comment: I will try it, but I think that there is no significant change form what I've wrote. Thnx anyway

Comment: Nope, no change. It still won't work. Also, by experimenting plugging in and out the ethernet cable, I realised that when I replug the cable, a bunch of data is automatically sent with the same timestamp (maybe saved in ram or some cache- this happens whenever i restart the programme as well but on smaller scale). Do you think there might be another way to get a back up? Maybe by writing everything on txt file and erasing the txt file after every 1GB of data (so that the SD won't get full- it's on a Raspberry Pi 2)?